# "Variable 'X' can be made constant", what does 'constant' mean?

Tags: typescript, resharper, ecmascript-6

VStudio or ReSharper is giving me the suggestion below:

[image]

What does constant mean in this scenario? If it's a constant in the current method scope, what's the purpose? Methods tend to be small and therefore it shouldn't give any advantage compared to be a regular var?

Please enligten me

Comment: Well, should the variable elems change from the initialized value, would you be happy? I don’t think so. Imagine the code 5 years from now, are you sure this method won’t grow?

Comment: @gurghet: I split methods that grow into smaller ones.

Comment: good job but that won’t solve much since you can’t be sure someone else is going to be in charge of that code later.

Comment: I'm answering your question from a software engineering standpoint. Not telling you who will manage your project. Team work dynamics is part of software engineering.

Comment: @gurghet: If the usage of const in the middle of functions is a decision that matters, then there is something fundamentally wrong with the architecture or the team. I can see the point with `const` in closures or class members.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's nothing complicated.

It's typically better to use `const` over `let` (and definitely `var`), since const makes it easier to understand code, since you only have to look at the initial assignment to know what the contents of the variable are. Use it as much as possible.

It should be noted that though constants can not be reassigned, in some cases their contents can, for example when dealing with an array or object. For example, `const x = [1]; x[0] = 2;` is perfectly valid code, but this should be considered an anti-pattern, because one would expect a constant to remain constant, thus breaking the [principle of least astonishment](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrincipleOfLeastAstonishment#:~:text=Principle%20Of%20Least%20Astonishment,the%20operation%20and%20other%20clues.&text=In%20addition%20to%20function%20naming,applies%20to%20user%20interface%20design.).

You can of course update an array with a `const` by simply creating a copy of the array and assigning it to a new `const`:

```
const x = [1];
const x2 = [...x, 2];
```

This does have performance considerations you might need to consider when dealing with extremely large arrays.

The `const` and `let` keywords are part of the ECMAScript 2015 standard. So when using `const` or `let` and transpiling down to older ECMAScript targets `const` and `let` are transpiled to the old `var`. Nowadays all [browsers support `const`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=const) and there are no real performance considerations for using one or the other.

Comment: Some browsers may not support 'const', because it's from ECMA script 6, which is not universially supported yet.  https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/  Thus it makes sense to use 'var' over 'const' for some audiences.  I guess the question is tagged for 6, but its not obvious from reading the question.

Comment: @MarkRogers The question DOES mention `typescript` explicitly. This will always have to be transpiled anyway before browsers can make sense of it. So the 'some audiences' you're talking about can safely use `const` instead of `var` given they're working in Typescript. Just as long as they don't set ECMAscript 6 as the target language, because then the typescript compiler would no longer transpile `const`s to `var`.